# Euclidean algorithm (JS)

Tags: javascript, pseudocode

(sorry for my english=/)
**This is the pseudo:**

```
function lnko(a, b)

  -if a = b then lnko := a 

  -if a < b then lnko := lnko(a, b-a) 

  -if a > b then lnko := lnko(a-b, b) 

function end
```

**And my Code is:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function run()
            {
                var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
                var b = document.getElementById("b").value;

                var s = lnko(a,b)
                document.write(a+"/"+b+"<br>"+(a/s)+"/"+(b/s));
            //  document.write("<br>"+s)
            }
        function lnko(a,b)
            {
                alert(a+"..."+b)
                if (a==b)
                    {
                        return a;
                    }
                if (a<b)
                    {
                        return lnko(a,(b-a));
                    }
                if (a>b)
                    {
                        return lnko((a-b),b);
                    }
            }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="a" />
    <input type="text" id="b" />
    <input type="button" onclick="run()" />
</body>
```

The problem is, if i call lnko with 10/5, 15/3,...etc it makes nothing..

Comment: _"it makes nothing"_ What is it supposed to make?

Comment: -1 You should have put more effort into explaining your issue. "*it makes nothing*" provides no information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you retrieve `a` and `b`, what you are getting is strings, rather than numbers, so that `lnko` is not doing what you expected. Specifically, that is causing problems in the comparison: `10 > 5` but `"10" < "5"`.

A concise way to fix this is:

```
var a = +document.getElementById("a").value;
var b = +document.getElementById("b").value;
```

As Pascal Belloncle points out, you could alternately use:

```
var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("a").value, 10);
var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("b").value, 10);
```

The big difference will be how malformed "numbers" like `42a` get treated. The first form (`+doc...`) fails to convert the value to a number and returns `NaN` while `parseInt` parses what it can and returns `42`.

Comment: or use parseInt() to be a bit more explicit.

Comment: @PascalBelloncle Note, however that `parseInt(x,10)` is not the same as `+x`.

Comment: @PascalBelloncle: good point! Clarified to show the difference.